# How to set an image under a text with bootstrap in a section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to set a text next to an image, and the image would go under the text on smartphone. And this configuration need to be in a section.

```
<section id = "s1">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <p class = "title text-center"> TITLE </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-6">
                
                <p class = "text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                 Mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. 
                 In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque 
                 sagittis purus sit.
                 </p>
                 
            </div> 
        
            <div class = "col-md-6">
                <img id = "image" class="img-fluid" src = "img_random.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
#s1 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red ;
}

.title {
    font-size: 3vw;
}

.text {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#image {
    height: 30vw;
    width: 30vw;
}
```

I noticed that picture was not under the text on smartphone, but was when i am only resizing the window of brave.

[when i'm resizing the window directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeIMX.png)

[when i'm resinzing the screen manually in the inspection mod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiSY9.png)

i noticed also that the text is setting normaly under the picture when code isn't in a section.

I was expecting to see the picture under the text on a smartphone, and more generaly when i'm resinzing the screen. It did, but only when resizing the window of brave, not on smartphone, or when resizing the screen in the inspection mode.

Answer (score 0):

We can add col-sm-12 classname when screensize under 540px our text will cover row then image will be under the text. You can change breakpoints for column pixel size look up doc[Bootstrap Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/)

```
            <p class = "text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
             Mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. 
             In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque 
             sagittis purus sit.
             </p>
             
        </div> 
    
        <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <img id = "image" class="img-fluid" src = "img_random.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```